# What is the complement of Cartesian product sets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If we have $K_1\subset \mathbb{Z}$, define the Cartesian product sets as
$$\Pi_{i=1}^{\infty}K_i$$
where $K_2, K_3, \dots =\mathbb{Z}$. This is a countable integers sequences $(a_1, a_2, \dots)$.

What is the complement of Cartesian product sets? It seems a complement of a countable integers sequences.

Comment: It's ather hard to understand what you mean and what is your motivation for that. Could explain a little more what you are after in more plain terms ?

Comment: You should be clear about what the ambient space is. Is it $\Bbb Z^{\Bbb N}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complement of $\prod_{i=1}^\infty K_i$ in $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is just

$(\Bbb Z\setminus K_1) \times \prod_{i=2}^\infty K_i$. The only way not to be in the set is for the first coordinate not be in $K_1$.

Comment: Why not consider $K_i^c, i\ge 2$?

Comment: @York what is the space in which we take a complement ?

Comment: Since $K_i=\mathbb{Z}, i\ge 2$. I am confused about it. Is it $\mathbb{Z}\setminus K_i =\emptyset$?

Comment: @York Yes, if the ambient space is $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z \times \ldots$. In general if $\prod_i A_i \subseteq \prod_i X_i$ the complement of the former is a union of product sets, as in $\Bbb R^2\setminus (A \times B) = ((\Bbb R\setminus A) \times \Bbb R) \cup (\Bbb R \times (\Bbb R\setminus B))$ for $A,B \subseteq \Bbb R$.

Comment: So why the complement of $\Pi_{i} K_i$ is just the complement of the first set $K_1$?

Comment: @York See the sentence "the only way.." That's the proof